# Не могу открыть порт 443 для исходящих запросов через iptables

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

Проверяю через команду nmap -Pn 81.163.25.202.

Консоль:

```
root@ubuntu:~# nmap -Pn 81.163.25.202                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                            
Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-01-24 14:16 MSK                                                                             
Nmap scan report for site.dev (81.163.25.202)                                                                                         
Host is up (0.0000060s latency).                                                                                                            
Not shown: 989 closed ports                                                                                                                 
PORT    STATE SERVICE                                                                                                                       
21/tcp  open  ftp                                                                                                                           
22/tcp  open  ssh                                                                                                                           
25/tcp  open  smtp                                                                                                                          
53/tcp  open  domain                                                                                                                        
80/tcp  open  http                                                                                                                          
110/tcp open  pop3                                                                                                                          
143/tcp open  imap                                                                                                                          
465/tcp open  smtps                                                                                                                         
587/tcp open  submission                                                                                                                    
993/tcp open  imaps                                                                                                                         
995/tcp open  pop3s                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                            
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.65 seconds
```

Пытался открыть порт 443 и через iptables, и через UFW – не выходит.

Не могу из скриптов делать CURL, прилетает ошибка.

```
cURL error 7: Failed to connect to domain.ru port 443: Connection refused (http_request_failed)
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что дело в фаерволе ? Может веб-сервер не настроен для работы с https и на 443 порту не слушает.

Comment: `Пытался открыть` — а вы его перед этим «закрывали»? вероятно, нет. так что же вы пытаетесь тогда «открыть»? может, вам всё-таки стоит озаботиться запуском процесса, который будет **слушать** это порт?